# If statement not recognizing variable c#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to get c# to speak voice when a variable called voice is set to true, but if voice is set to true or false it does still uses voice. Could someone help?

```
private void turnVoiceOffToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       bool voice = false;
    }



private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentAvailableMemory = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();
        richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("There are currently {0} megabytes of memory available.\r\n", currentAvailableMemory.ToString()));
        if (voice == true);
        {
            synth.Speak(String.Format("There are currently {0} megabytes of memory available.\r\n", currentAvailableMemory.ToString()));
        }
```

Comment: How does that even compile? Are you not including all of the code?

Comment: And for goodness sake, say `if( voice )` instead of `if( voice == true )`.

Answer (score 3):

`voice` is a *local* variable in `turnVoiceOffToolStripMenuItem_Click`.  It is not accessible in `button2_Click`.  You *could* make it a field or property of the class, but it's not clear if that's the *right* way to do it.

**EDIT**

Given that your code seems to compile, you apparently already have a class member for `voice` (or else it wouldn't compile).  If the extraneous semicolon at the end of your `if` statement is the only issue then your question should be closed as a typographical error (or at best a duplicate of an existing question).

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of `if (voice == true);`.

Comment: Should not it be a comment?

Comment: If the semicolon is the only problem then the question should be closed as a typo.

Comment: @DStanley I agree.  Which category do we select on the 'close' dialog?

Comment: @MikeNakis It's the 5th sub-choice when you choose "Off-Topic"

Comment: @DStanley heheee... you are not voting to close because you don't want to lose the points!  C-:=  fair enough!  C-:=

Comment: @MikeNakis No, I'm waiting to see if the OP confirms that the semicolon is the only problem.  I could care less about the points - I'll delete my answer if it makes you feel better. (BTW, you don't lose points for answers to closed questions - they have to be permanently deleted)

Comment: @DStanley Oh, I see. No man, it would not make me feel better.

Comment: Have a problem no voice happens no matter what the variable is set too